# Unix behavior with two different processes holding descriptor to the same file and one process deleting the file

Tags: file, unix, system, kernel

I'm a Unix newbie. I have two processes holding handles(file descriptors) to the same file
on the disk.

Let the processes be A, B and the file sample.txt say

Process A is a producer (writes data to the disk file) and process B is a consumer (reads 
from the disk file).

Process A has reached a point where it closed the file handle (descriptor) to the disk file
sample.txt, deleted the file from disk and opened a new file with the same name 
"sample.txt" and started writing to the new file. Meanwhile process B still has the old 
descriptor which points to the old file which was deleted by the process A.

Now, what happens when process B tries to read the file using it's old descriptor and will
it still be able to read the old "sample.txt" file completely till the end?

Unix gurus, please throw some light on this. Any pointers to Unix kernel documents are
greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel maintains a reference count for each opened file. Second process (B) will be reading from the original file, which will not be removed from the disk until that second process closes the file descriptor, though no other processes will be able to open that old version of the file.

#### Edit 0:

In a little bit more detail - each file in a file system is represented by an [`inode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), then multiple [directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28file_systems%29) can point to it (these are [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)). So there are *two* reference counts here - on-disk link count, and in-kernel count of `open(2)` calls on given file (no matter through which link). A file is only removed, i.e. its `inode` recycled, when both counts go to zero.

To translate that to your example - When process `A` removes the original file, the directory entry is removed, the `inode` link count goes to zero, but not the `open()`-count. The `inode` is still not-free until process `B` calls `close(2)`.

Comment: I write some sample code in c to simulate what processes A and B does. The condition when process A closes and deletes the file is when the file reaches a size of 32MB. It worked in most of my runs but in a few runs process B returns an error which says the offset at which it is trying to read is not valid with out even reaching the EOF. Can this be explainded?

Comment: Hmm, anything can be explained with enough effort :) Would you mind showing some code?

Comment: I tried this on a different Unix server which i donot have access to currently. Will post the code as soon i can access it.